# What is the life span of a weak (vs strong) object reference?

Tags: objective-c, swift, memory-leaks, closures, automatic-ref-counting

It just occurred to me... 
That I believe that the **life** of a weak reference is tied to the scope of that reference (within function or global).

So I wonder, as long as I keep the processing of data within a particular scope, then I should be okay with using **weak** vs **strong** references.   Correct?

The reason I'm asking... is that I was told that one organization has a policy of keeping blocks/closure 'weak' by default to avoid accidental retain cycles.

Comment: Is this a Swift or Objective-C question and if you're trying to emphasise those all capital words there are better ways like _italic_ or **bold**, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: For both languages.   This is merely an abstract question.
Makes sense; normally I would have done that.  Done.

Comment: In ObjC, `weak` references are only valid for as long as the object remains viable.  That may be through the end of scope or it may not.   If you do `weakVar = [[NSObject alloc] init];` the object will be immediately deallocated and the compiler will warn, for example.

Comment: So a weak reference could be deallocated at any time, should the system needs to claim the storage; and hence the use of strong reference.

Answer (score 2):

> one organization has a policy of keeping blocks/closure 'weak' by
>   default to avoid accidental retain cycles.

Probably, the organization has a policy of keeping *references captured by blocks* 'weak' to avoid retain cycles.  The blocks themselves, kept as properties, are copied.

There's a very specific circumstance where a block causes a retain cycle: the block refers to an object (self, or some other object) and that object (directly or indirectly) retains the block.

Most of the time, we know through examination what object will be retaining a block. Say that's "objectA".  The retain cycle question is: do any of the objects referred to in the block directly or indirectly retain "objectA"?  Those objects, **and no others**, must be declared weak for use within the block.

Declaring them all weak all the time will do the job, but, IMO, will make the future readers of this code worry that the authors didn't have a firm understanding of their own code.

Comment: _will make the future readers of this code worry that the authors didn't have a firm understanding of their own code_ that or if it's a junior developer he/she might just think this is a must. The end result would be an incorrect paradigm shift!